# Combinatorics: Participants in a match

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In a tournament, each of the $6$ participants played 2 matches against each of the other participants. What was the total number of matches played during the tournament?

So we have a set of 6 participants.

$A, B, C, D, E, F$

So $A$ can play with either $B, C, D, E, F$ and likewise for the other participants.

$A$ has $5$ options, $A$ can choose $2$ options.

But, how can we solve this? I can just base the layout, nothing else =(

Comment: @satishramanathan Have you taken into account that there are *two* games between e.g. participants A and B?

Comment: I misread the question, I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's say "naievely": each of the $6$ participants plays $5\times 2=10$ matches, so there will be $6\times 10=60$ matches in total. Then realize that the match $A$ against $B$ is counted twice this way: as a match played by $A$ and as a match played by $B$. This is true for each match. We can repair this by dividing the number we found on the naive way by $2$ resulting in a total of $30$ matches.

Comment: thank you for your response. The correct answer is 30 as you have written. However: Each of the $6$ participants play $6(2) = 12$ matches not $10$ matches. What is your reasoning?

Comment: Participant A plays matches against $5$ opponents: B,C,D,E,F. Not a match against himself.

Comment: okay. How do you know how much you are overcounting by? You say 2; how do you exactly know?? Thanks!

Comment: Because a match is between $2$ distinct participants. For both (i.e. for $2$) it has been counted in the naive sense as one of their matches.

Comment: almost there. Oh, so you are counting it for both, hence the 2 overcount?

Comment: *Every* match is in the naive sense counted for both of the participants (hence it is counted twice). That is repaired by dividing the "naive" number $60$ by $2$.

Comment: Okay, sort of better. Now, Each of the 6 participants **can** play $5*2 = 10* matches but they only play 2 matches though

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding. Your question starts with: "**each** of the $6$ participants plays $2$ matches against **each** of the other participants". I answered on that. This is confirmed by your comment that $30$ is indeed the correct answer. Then in your question: "A can choose $2$ options." Is this your interpretation of the question? If so then it is most probably a wrong interpretation. It cannot possibly lead to (the correct) $30$ matches.

Comment: $A$ can play matches with 5 others. Suppose $B, C, D, E, F$ can do the same. $A \implies 2*5 = 10$ because at most, $A$ has the ability to play 2 matches against $B, C, D, E, F$

Multiply by 6, you get $60$ total matches are possible if two matches are played with each other. So If two matches are played with ALL 5 other contestants. Then you realize, that you counted A playing B as seperate and B playing A as seperate, you divide by 2. $= 30$

Answer (score 0):

I am reposting my revised comment.

A plays 2 games with each of the other five players $= 5*2$

B plays 2 games with each of the other four players, (A needs to be discounted this time because A playing B is the same as B playing A) $= 4*2$

Thus the argument extends to rest of the cases.
...
Goes on until

E plays 2 games with one player $= 1*2$

Add them all :  $2\times(5+4+3+2+1)= 6*5 = 30$.

In a combinatorial way it is ${6\choose2}\times 2  = 30$

Comment: But A can only play with 2 players. because he can only play 2 matches

Comment: Your problem statement says, "each of the 6 participants played 2 matches **against each of the other participants**". Could it mean that A plays two games with two other participants.

Comment: Please see the reworded answer and if you find my answer useful, could you accept my solution